# Regex capturing groups

Tags: regex

I want to capture groups of alphabets separated by (), for example:

String: ab(cad)xy(bc)an
Groups should contain: ab, cad, xy, bc, an

I tried this regex:
([a-z]+)+
But it is only capturing the last group. I read about multiple capturing and tried this:
(?:([a-z]+)+)
But the result is same. I am doing something wrong here. Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need capturing groups to match/capture every instance of letter characters. The following regular expression is enough, simply reference Group index 0 for the match results.

```
[a-z]+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

`(([a-z]+)\(([a-z]+)\))+([a-z]+)?`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJ9fU0/1).
However, you'd better know the maximum number of such groups, and use named captruing groups (if the language allows). Group capturing only makes sense when you know what you are capturing. E.g. "ab" = "code 1", "cad" = "Canadian dollar", "xy" = "Math variables", "bc" = "Era", "an" = "Article used". :) Otherwise, just matches are OK and you can use Jeffrey's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For groups of non-parenthesis:

```
([^\)\(]+)
```

For groups of letters:

```
([A-z]+)
```

In all cases - http://regexpal.com is your friend.